# offset() of element after prepending another element

Tags: jquery, offset

I'm having an issue with jQuerys `offset()`

I have some `<img>` in the document. On document ready, I wrap that image into a div and prepend some text. Then I need the image offset.

How can I get the offset of the image AFTER the prepend has been done?

Here is a sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>Image Offset Problem!?</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function(){
            $img = $('#demoimg');

            // I hope this has nothing to do with it... it's just too big
            $img.width(800);

            var $prependDiv = $('<div>Some text</div>');
            var $wrap = $img.wrap('<div id="wrapper">').parent();
            //$wrap.prepend($prependDiv);

            // Here I need to use the FINAL offset, the one with the value that shows when we click the button.
            // Instead, I get something else!
            var imgOffset = $img.offset();
            console.log('offset().top = ' + imgOffset.top);
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <img id="demoimg" src="demoimg.jpg" />
    <input type="button" value="View image offset().top" onclick="calculateOffset()" />
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculateOffset() {
        console.log('offset().top = ' + $('#demoimg').offset().top);
    };
</script>
```

I need to access the `offset()`.top right there in the `$(document).ready()` function.

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: I've reopened your question. Please add your solution as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to redefine `$img` after wrapping it using `.wrap()`, since the dom reference has changed.

Try reselecting the element like this:

```
var imgOffset = $('#demoimg').offset();
```

Or redefine `$img` after using `.wrap()`:

```
...
$img = $('#demoimg');
var imgOffset = $img.offset();
...
```

Comment: On FF it still outputs 13 on document.ready(), but 28 on button click